# PHP download file?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to create a download thing for a file in PHP. It will download from the server to the local computer.

Here is the code that I have for now:

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "files.000webhost.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "jonasvdr", "*******");

$local_file = "image";
$server_file = "https://jonasvdr.000webhostapp.com/uploads/NewlogoNoBackGround.png";

// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
} else {
    echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

The error that I am getting is this:

> Warning: ftp_get(): Can't open https://jonasvdr.000webhostapp.com/uploads/NewlogoNoBackGround.png: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd5/555/3642555/public_html/download.php on line 11

I've tried to just put uploads/NewlogoNoBackGround.png instead of the whole URL but got the same result.

This PHP page is in the main root directory, and in that directory is a map called uploads. That is where the file's in. How can I get that file then?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `https://jonasvdr.000webhostapp.com/uploads/NewlogoNoBackGround.png` to be a valid file name.  That looks suspiciously like an HTTP URL.

Comment: You need to pass the path of the file on the server's filesystem relative to the FTP root. You're passing its URL.

Comment: ehhh. I'm new to PHP. How would i do that?

Comment: Just the pathname `"/uploads/NewlogoNoBackGrou‌​nd.png"`

Comment: Why are you using FTP to do it instead of just just `copy($server_file, $local_file)`?

Comment: Barmar, i could do that but then i still have to define the server  file path. That's where the problem is here....

Comment: If you login with GUI FTP client, and navigate to the respective folder, what path to you see in the file panel?

Comment: hi. What's GUI FTP?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the file through its URL, not its filepath. Try:

```
$server_file = '/uploads/NewlogoBackGround.png';
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$server_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/NewlogoBackground.png';
```

Depending on where exactly your file is and what file structure you have.

Comment: Doesn't work... For both i'm geting "No such file or directory in /storage/ssd5/555/3642555/public_html/download.php on line 11
Error downloading /uploads/NewlogoBackGround.png."